# Query regarding post comments using Facebook Javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

As per the Facebook Javascript API documentation, I need an APP Id to post comments on facebook wall. But  when I log in to my Facebook account it always shows me “All Campaigns" page and I am not able to access “Apps” section to create new application and get APP Id which can be used in JavaScript API.
Can you please suggest how can I create an APP Id in my account and post comment on my facebook wall from external web pages using Facebook Javascript API.

Answer (score 0):

You can view/create apps on Facebook for this purpose in the [developers](http://developers.facebook.com) section. It sounds like you want to look at 'Build for Websites'. When you have made an app, it will appear in the [apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) section, where you can find your App ID and App Secret keys, as well as manage/edit the app.

Comment: but i can't see the "APPS" link or tab to create the new application, when i logged in it always show me the normal “All Campaigns" page and when i tried to logged in with facebook/developer it shows me the same “All Campaigns" page.
please someone help me to get out of this and suggest way to create new application.

Thanks

your early response will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to access “Apps” section to create new application

What exactly does „not being able” mean?

Is your account *verified* with Facebook (via text to mobile, credit card info)? That’s a basic requirement for becoming a developer on the FB platform.